# finding mean and variance

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Suppose that the weight of a person selected at random from some
population is normally distributed with parameters $\mu$ (mean) and $\sigma$ (variance). Suppose also that $P(X \le  160) = 1/2$ and $P(X \le 140) = 1/4.$ Find $\mu$ and $\sigma,$
and find $P(X \ge 200).$ Of all the people in the population weighing at
least 200 pounds, what percentage will weigh over 220 pounds?

Comment: I  formatted your question. I'm thinking you may have intended to say that $\sigma$ is the standard deviation, not the variance. If so, please edit.

Answer (score 0):

**HINTS**

1. If $X \sim \mathcal{N}(0, 1)$ what are the values of $a,b$ such that $\mathbb{P}[X \le a] = 1/2$ and $\mathbb{P}[X\le b] = 1/4$?
2. How do you convert $Y \sim \mathcal{N}(\mu, \sigma)$ to $X \sim \mathcal{N}(0, 1)$?

Answer (score 0):

From $P(X \le 160) = 1/2,$ you can infer that $\mu = 160.$
Then from 
$$P(X \le 140) = \left(\frac{X-\mu}{\sigma}\le \frac{140 - 160}{\sigma} \right)
= P\left(Z \le \frac{-20}{\sigma} \right) = 1/4,$$
You can find $-20/\sigma$ and thus $\sigma.$

Then, knowing both $\mu$ and $\sigma,$ you are ready to find
$P(X \ge 200).$

*Note:* In principle, if you are given values of *any* two probabilities
of the type $P(X \le a)$ and $P(X \le b),$ where $a \ne b$ are both
known, then you can solve two equations in two unknowns to get $\mu$ and
$\sigma.$